# Is it possible to resize/reposition layouts in android at runtime?

Tags: android-layout

I am developing an application in android, in which the UI looks almost similar to igoogle. I wanted to know if I can reposition the layouts in android like how its done igoogle page. Please provide me some sample code if anyone has already done it. Also I wanted to know if we can re-size the layout at runtime.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

To make an "igoogle" like interface you probably want to use a grid of some kind. [Here is a library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4036) that can provide an appropriate View while allowing reordering of the items.

As for your last question, yes, the size of the Views that you place in the grid can be adjusted as well. Using simple [layoutparams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html).